# Xephyr: server does not have extension for -dpms option

Tags: x-server, dpms, xephyr, xset

when I open new openbox session in Xephyr, the screen goes blank after 10 minutes of inactivity.

How can I disable this ?

I tried this command:

```
xset -dpms s off
```

but get following error:

```
server does not have extension for -dpms option
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably something like a screen saver or locker, not dpms. Try just `xset s off` without any `-dpms`.